# Google Earth: Pan the camera

Tags: google-earth-plugin, panning

Although it should be something really basic, I cannot find how to pan the camera in Google Earth, I mean, here https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/camera_control

They say that it is possible to pan the camera like that, but it's not really a true panning.

I would like to set a point on the globe and then rotate the view, like viewing from the North/East or so. But it doesn't seem to be possible.

I would like to find a function like setPan(), since there is also setTilt() and setRoll().

I also cannot find a way to possibly set camera and lookAt together, and it seems to accept or one or the other.

Comment: It is panning, you just need to make very small increments if you wish it to be imperceivable. LookAt and Camera both set the current view, therefore you can only use one at a time.... unless you run two instances of GE. You want to set a point and then rotate view, use LookAt, it defines a certain spot on the Earth that is the focus of attention - then change various attributes and GE will continue to make sure the chosen spot is still in the center of the view. If you wish to view from the north, change the <heading> to either 0 or 180, can't remember which one it is.

Comment: well, I don't really get why they made it this way and why is not explained in any docs. And why someone wants to close this.